# Test if SSH private key has password protection

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm trying to test if `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is actually password protected.

When you run `ssh-keygen` you can choose an empty password, and I'm trying to detect this.

Is that possible with a one-liner?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you open the private key file in text editor you will be able to see `ENCRYPTED` in the second line of the RSA/DSA key file. 
For example:

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,373B504621779D53C72BADE597C531A0
```

Comment: Just verified on CentOS 7, looks good

Comment: Unless you are using the new OpenSSH key format.

Comment: And if you are using the new OpenSSH key format?

Answer (score 17):

If you execute:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/name_of_key
```

you will get key printed if there is no password like this:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3M....
```

If there is password of the key you will be asked for it

Comment: To add to this, `SSH_ASKPASS=/bin/false ssh-keygen -y -f test_rsa < /dev/null` will simply fail instead of asking for the password.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I add here.

Thanks to  @Ulrich-Schwarz , I extended his answer to check all my keys (the one i generated, so I have the puublic/private pair) in my $HOME/.ssh/ :

```
for l in $(ls $HOME/.ssh/*.pub)
do         key=${l%.*}
   if SSH_ASKPASS=/bin/false ssh-keygen -y -f $key < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
   then
       echo -n "NO  password: "
   else
       echo -n "YES password: "
   fi
   echo ${key}
done
```

Comment: Adding the loop is useful. You swapped the 'YES' and 'NO' though; if the command is successful then no password is present.

Comment: thanks @Quantum7 , now should be ok.